# How to cycle through vim marks

Tags: vim

To go to the next line with a (lowercase) mark, I can do:

- <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>

And to go to the previous mark I can do:

- <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>

However, let's say I have 10 marks in the file and I am at the last one. Is there a way to cycle through to the first mark from the last one (like how search does "Search hit bottom. Continuing from Top".)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to cycle through to the first mark from the last one

Supply big count. E.g. `26['`. To wrap it into a script:

```
" our mappings with counter support
nnoremap <silent>[' :<C-U>call NextMark(-v:count1)<CR>
nnoremap <silent>]' :<C-U>call NextMark(v:count1)<CR>

function! NextMark(incr) abort
    " save current line number
    let l:lnum = line('.')
    " go to the next lowercase mark
    execute printf("normal! %d%s'", abs(a:incr), a:incr > 0 ? ']' : '[')
    if l:lnum == line('.')
        " no move, assume it's the last (or the first) one
        if stridx(&shortmess, 's') < 0
            " print message as with n/N
            echohl WarningMsg
            echo printf("search hit %s, continuing at %s",
                \ a:incr > 0 ? 'BOTTOM' : 'TOP', a:incr > 0 ? 'TOP' : 'BOTTOM')
            echohl NONE
        endif
        " jump to the first (or last) lowercase mark
        execute printf("normal! 26%s'", a:incr > 0 ? '[' : ']')
    endif
endfunction
```